# Bar plot with a few extreme values

Tags: r, graph, plot, bar-chart, outliers

Consider the following vector:

```
vec <- c(-0.137042293280008 ,-0.0085530023889108 ,7.696986350237e-05 ,9.85275557252565e-05 ,0.000246261331270769 ,-0.0013658222244989 ,0.00117046787783182 ,-0.000423648394606887 ,-0.000112607126438433 ,0.00212185051472275 ,-0.000110104526782098)
names(vec) <- paste("var", 1:length(vec), sep = " ")
```

I would like to plot `vec` using a `bar plot` in R. However, as you can see, there is one or two values that are extreme compared to the rest of the vector. When the bar plot is drawn, the small values barely show on the graph.

```
par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i', mai = c(0.5,2,0.5,1.5))
bp2 <- barplot(vec, horiz = TRUE, col = "lightblue4", border = "lightblue4", yaxt = 'n', cex.axis = 0.7)
axis(2, at = bp2, labels = names(vec), tick = FALSE, las = 2, cex.axis = 0.7)
```

[image]

Is there a way to better display the chart? For example, is there a way to eventually split the x-axis? The graph below is an (unrelated) example, but it shows how the y-axis in this case is split to allow for all values to show on the graph.

P.S: Plotting with a log-scale is not an option in my case, as some of the vector values are negative.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Would it be possible to use some other transformation, such as sign(x) * log(abs(x))?

Comment: You may have a look at `gap.barplot` in the `plotrix` package, which basically produces a plot like the lower one.

Comment: @ChristopherLouden Unfortunately, no. The interpretation of the graph wouldn't be intuitive.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612348/break-x-axis-in-r/19612566#19612566) can be useful for you.

Comment: @Jiber It is helpful indeed. Thanks! However, I am still trying to figure out how to work that function with a bar chart..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `gap.barplot` from plotrix package. Take a look at this:

```
library(plotrix)
gap.barplot(vec,gap=c(-0.12,-0.04),xlab="Index",ytics=c(-0.04,-0.02,0),
            ylab="",main="Barplot with gap", horiz=TRUE)
```

Modify `gap` and `ytics` argument to get the desired aesthetic for your plot.

[image]