# break bar to see the difference between small and big values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some values that i want to plot in a `geom_bar()` chart.
the problem with the data is, that most values are small (0:100) and some values are big (50000:30000000).

Is it possible to break the bar of these large values, that the axis goes from 0 to 100 and then from 50000 to the largest values with a visible gap in between?

Comment: Not easily, no. (Broken axes are often considered "bad practice" and ggplot will rarely make that sort of thing easy, or even possible.) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19612348/324364) for alternatives.

Comment: No, but if you post some more data you could get some workaround

Comment: @joran: so would you consider making two plots? for example one for the large and one for the small values?

Comment: Maybe. Using a log scale is another option to try.

Comment: @joran: unfortuately when using a log scale, you can not see the difference of the small values though