# How to shrink bars and axes in a barplot when the value range is high

Tags: r, plot

I have to plot data including one group with high amount of values. So the barplot in total is very high.

Today I've seen a nice plot on [heise.de](http://www.heise.de/tp/bild/37/37513/37513_1.html#bild):

[image]

How can I implement the "cuts" with R?

Comment: I'd simply use a log scale on the y-axis.

Comment: The package `plotrix` has a way to [add an axis break](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19612348/1199289).