# ggplot2 - only use subset of x values for ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have a dataframe where there are too many x values to display nicely as ticks on a plot. These ticks are in YYYY-MM format, i.e. 2016-04.

Is there a way I can only show, for instance, every 6th value of x as a tick on the x-axis?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027532/break-y-axis-in-ggplot2/36027879#36027879). It shows how you can define what labels you want and where using scale_x_continuous or scale_y_continuous.

Comment: Could you provide sample code to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I used
`scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%Y-%m")`