# plot time series with discontinuous axis in R

Tags: r, date, plot, plotrix

I want to plot a time series, excluding in the plot a stretch of time in the middle. If I plot the series alone, with only an index on the x-axis, that is what I get. The interior set of excluded points do not appear.

```
x <- rnorm(50)
Dates <- seq(as.Date("2008-1-1"), by = "day", length.out = length(x))
dummy <- c(rep(1, 25), rep(0, 10), rep(1, length(x) - 35))
plot(x[dummy == 1])
```

Once the dates are on the x-axis, however, R dutifully presents an accurate true time scale, including the excluded dates. This produces a blank region on the plot.

```
plot(Dates[dummy == 1], x[dummy == 1])
```

How can I get dates on the x-axis, but not show the blank region of the excluded dates?

Comment: Doing so would break your x-axis, which is not a good idea. You could put the remaining parts into ggplot facets, perhaps.

Comment: Why not @alistaire? Is it bad form/misleading, or bad for a more technical reason?

Comment: I had in mind something like `plot(x[dummy == 1], xaxt = "n")` and then using `axis` to put the dates in (or an equivalent construct in `ggplot`) but couldn't figure out how to add the dates using the `dummy == 1` subset.

Comment: The meaning of the positioning in the x-direction would vary based on where you are on the graph, instead of having a single consistent relationship. That's misleading; it will make data points look closer than they in fact are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three alternatives:

**1. ggplot2** Apparently, `ggplot2` [would not allow for a discontinuous axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194688/using-ggplot2-can-i-insert-a-break-in-the-axis) but you could use `facet_wrap` to get a similar effect.

```
# get the data
  x = rnorm(50)
  df <- data.frame( x = x,
                  Dates = seq(as.Date("2008-1-1"), by = "day", length.out = length(x)) ,
                  dummy = c(rep(1, 25), rep(0, 10), rep(1, length(x) - 35)))

  df$f <- ifelse(df$Dates <= "2008-01-25",  c("A"), c("B")) 

# plot
  ggplot( subset(df, dummy==1)) +
    geom_point(aes(x= Dates, y=x)) +
    facet_wrap(~f , scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

**2. base R**

```
plot(df$x ~ df$Dates, col= ifelse( df$f=="A", "blue", "red"), data=subset(df, dummy==1))
```

[image]

**3. plotrix** [Another alternative would be to use `gap.plot{plotrix}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612348/break-x-axis-in-r). The code would be something like this one below. However, I couldn't figure out how to make a break in an axis with `date` values. Perhaps this would and additional  question.

```
library(plotrix)

gap.plot(Dates[dummy == 1], x[dummy == 1], gap=c(24,35), gap.axis="x")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to impose a gap in the plot. I want the opposite: the standard plot has a gap that I don't want.

Comment: I've corrected the code. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks. One note for total newbies like me: the data.table command in the ggplot solution (1) can be replaced by data.frame and then doesn't need another package.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Along the lines I proposed above, I had to fiddle with the `axis` command for a long time to get it to put the date labels in the right place. Here's what I used:

```
plot(x[dummy == 1], xaxt = "n", xlab = "")  # plot with no x-axis title or tick labels
Dates1_index <- seq(1,length(Dates1), by = 5)  # set the tick positions
axis(1, at = Dates1_index, labels = format(Dates1[Dates1_index], "%b %d"), las = 2)
```

Having succeeded, I now agree with @alistaire that it looks pretty misleading. Maybe if I put a vertical dashed line at the break...