# Is there a way to use R to break chart axis and break linear regression line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linear-regression

I'm trying to figure out how to modify a scatter-plot that contains two groups of data along a continuum separated by a large gap. The graph needs a break on the x-axis as well as on the regression line.

This R code using the ggplot2 library accurately presents the data, but is unsightly due to the vast amount of empty space on the graph. Pearson's correlation is -0.1380438.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(, aes(x = dis, y = result[, 1])) + geom_point(shape = 1) +
  xlab("X-axis") +
  ylab("Y-axis") + geom_smooth(color = "red", method = "lm", se = F) + theme_classic()
p + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14))
```

[image]

This R code uses gap.plot to produce the breaks needed, but the regression line doesn't contain a break and doesn't reflect the slope properly. As you can see, the slope of the regression line isn't as sharp as the graph above and there needs to be a visible distinction in the slope of the line between those disparate groups.

```
library(plotrix)
gap.plot(
  x = dis,
  y = result[, 1],
  gap = c(700, 4700),
  gap.axis = "x",
  xlab = "X-Axis",
  ylab = "Y-Axis",
  xtics = seq(0, 5575, by = 200)
)
abline(v = seq(700, 733) , col = "white") 
abline(lm(result[, 1] ~ dis), col = "red", lwd = 2)
axis.break(1, 716, style = "slash")
```

[image]

Using MS Paint, I created an approximation of what the graph **should** look like. Notice the break marks on the top as well as the discontinuity between on the regression line between the two groups.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? (see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Break the data into 2 groups then use facet

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/60005173/786542

Comment: The slopes in the two regions should be the same since the ranges over which they are plotted are the same, not as you have illustrated but rather with a level shift downward. The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to plot the regression line in two pieces, using `ablineclip` to limit what's plotted each time.  (Similar to @tung's suggestion, although it's clear that you want the appearance of a single graph rather than the appearance of facets.)  Here's how that would work:

```
library(plotrix)

# Simulate some data that looks roughly like the original graph.
dis = c(rnorm(100, 300, 50), rnorm(100, 5000, 100))
result = c(rnorm(100, 0.6, 0.1), rnorm(100, 0.5, 0.1))

# Store the location of the gap so we can refer to it later.
x.axis.gap = c(700, 4700)

# gap.plot() works internally by shifting the location of the points to be
# plotted based on the gap size/location, and then adjusting the axis labels
# accordingly.  We'll re-compute the second half of the regression line in the
# same way; these are the new values for the x-axis.
dis.alt = dis - x.axis.gap[1]

# Plot (same as before).
gap.plot(
  x = dis,
  y = result,
  gap = x.axis.gap,
  gap.axis = "x",
  xlab = "X-Axis",
  ylab = "Y-Axis",
  xtics = seq(0, 5575, by = 200)
)
abline(v = seq(700, 733), col = "white")
axis.break(1, 716, style = "slash")

# Add regression line in two pieces: from 0 to the start of the gap, and from
# the end of the gap to infinity.
ablineclip(lm(result ~ dis), col = "red", lwd = 2, x2 = x.axis.gap[1])
ablineclip(lm(result ~ dis.alt), col = "red", lwd = 2, x1 = x.axis.gap[1] + 33)
```

[image]