# How to delete x axis that do not contain value using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, bioconductor, genome

I am using gggenes to plot a gene arrow map, however the genes are far from each other which make the plot unreadable. I wondering if there an method that can delete the area that do not contain genes.

Data example:

```
Genome  start   end state   id  gene
koreense    -68765  -69505  reverse WP_165607793.1  dsrN
koreense    -40289  -40585  reverse WP_069393961.1  sat
koreense    -23366  -24769  reverse WP_084228866.1  dsrA
koreense    -14754  -14957  reverse WP_085302191.1  sat
koreense    -7192   -7686   reverse WP_069391389.1  dsrA
koreense    -4858   -5154   reverse WP_069393961.1  sat
koreense    -3072   -3554   reverse WP_085304442.1  sat
koreense    -1258   -1503   reverse WP_085303636.1  sat
koreense    198 1013    forward WP_085304930.1  sat
koreense    29324   29524   forward WP_085304899.1  dsrB
koreense    33707   35119   forward WP_085304857.1  dsrN
koreense    152477  152875  forward WP_069392762.1  sat
```

My code is:

```
ggplot(gene, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = Genome, fill = gene)) +
  geom_gene_arrow() +
  facet_wrap(~ Genome, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") + 
  theme_genes() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line())
```

Example Data:

```
enter code here
```

The plot I got is:
[image]

What I expect is to use "//" to break the x axis like:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't think you can do it with `ggplot`. Try `plotrix` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612348/break-x-axis-in-r

Comment: 1) Please include data in reproducible format? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). 2) Include all the non-base libraries that you are using.